# exceptions.AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Tracker_create' OpenCV 3.1.0 Python 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I am getting below error at `tracker = cv2.Tracker_create("BOOSTING")`while executing my program. Any idea about how to resolve it ?

[image: module' object has no attribute]

Comment: May be You are using Old OpenCV Version, Try Installing OpenCV 3.1

Comment: @ZdaR Isn't this bit from `opencv_contrib`? I bet the OP is just using the standard build that doesn't include any of the contrib stuff. There's bound to be dozens of questions about that lying around, I see it all the time.